# How to Fix the copy/paste feature when two screens point to the same graph

Tags: acumatica

I've made two versions of the AP303000 and AR303000 screens (vendor and customers).

The PXGraph is not customized, but I created a new screen which is basically a copy of the AP303000, has the sitemap node AP303001 and is a simplified view of the original screen (it has way less fields, and a few custom fields without any business logic changed).

The problem is now I can't copy/paste anymore (on the original screen which is still in use), the feature is still here, but it seems i'm never able to paste (it stays grey).

If I unpublish the two custom screens, the feature works fine.

If I remove my custom screen from the sitemap, the feature works fine as well.

I contacted the support and they told me to add :

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;

namespace CUSTOMDEV
{
    public class VendorMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
    {
        public delegate bool CanClipboardCopyPasteDelegate();
        [PXOverride]
        public virtual bool CanClipboardCopyPaste(CanClipboardCopyPasteDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            return Base.Accessinfo.ScreenID == "AP.30.30.00";  // compare screen id to determine where it should be available
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't change anything, they also told me they can't help me more without a developper support plan, so they redirected me to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is related to the `Primary` notion. When a DAC is manipulated by many graphs there is pattern that selects which Graph should be used based on some DAC field values.

The vendor DAC is already targeting two Primary Graph based on the value of BAccount.BAccountID:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(new Type[] {
                typeof(VendorMaint),
                typeof(EP.EmployeeMaint)},
                new Type[] {
                typeof(Select<AP.Vendor, Where<AP.Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>),
                typeof(Select<EP.EPEmployee, Where<EP.EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>) 
                })]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm failing to grasp how I could use this sample to solve my problem. Should I create a new graph with this attribute and have my AP303001 connect to this PXGraph ?

Comment: The attribute goes on DAC. If you have a graph that manipulates Vendor as its Primary DAC it would preferably be in there too. I couldn't find documentation on how to override PXPrimaryGraph though. I have some doubt about it working on extensions so I don't have a final solution to provide either besides using another DAC that inherits from Vendor. And it's only speculation that it affects the copy/paste functionality.

Comment: No both my Graph have BAccount as primary DAC, also only the DAC Baccount is customized.

Comment: AP303000 is bound to VendorMaint graph which has VendorR has it's primary DAC. There's also some shenanigans going on with PXSubstitute attribute on the VendorR DAC. Your screen might still be a copy of AP303000 but I don't think it matters much if it's bound to a different primary DAC. They aren't the same, perhaps that difference is significant to the copy/paste functionality.